# Sending an Intent changes the type of the Extra parameter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity from where I start a second activity like so:

```
public void onItemSelected(long id) {

    // start the detail activity for the selected item ID.
    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, FeedDetailActivity.class);
    detailIntent.putExtra(FeedDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
    startActivityForResult(detailIntent, DETAIL_REQUEST_ID);
}
```

In the secondary activity I do this:

```
if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID))
{
    long id = getArguments().getLong(ARG_ITEM_ID);
    [...]
}
```

But I get a class cast exception when that getLong is executed stating the parameter is a java.lang.Integer. I was running this in the debugger and noticed that the Intent is created with id of type Long, but it is received with id of type Integer with the value set to 0 (see screenshots).

[image: The intent as I create it] 
The Intent as I create it

[image]
The intent as I receive it

What is going on?

Comment: getArgument is used to get data in fragments not in  activtiy in Activity you have to use getIntent().gteStringExtra("key_value");

Comment: It is a fragment activity (as you can see from the screens) .. so that should be OK ..

Comment: Had you tried of setArguments() for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `Intent` to `FeedDetailActivity`. But reading extras from the `FeedDetailFragment` which is inside the `FeedDetailActivity` I think so. So getting wrong value.

**Try this approach**

First of all read extras from onCreate method of `FeedDetailActivity` as we read read from an activity.

```
if(getIntent().hasExtras(ARG_ITEM_ID) {
 id = getIntent().getLongExtra(ARG_ITEM_ID);
}
```

Create Fragment using `beginTransaction().replace(/*YourContainer*/, FeedDetailFragment.getInstance(id))`

Create a function in `FeedDetailFragment` as

```
public static FeedDetailFragment getInstance(long userId) {
        FeedDetailFragment mFragment = new FeedDetailFragment();
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putLong(ARG_ITEM_ID, userId);
        mFragment.setArguments(mBundle);
        return mFragment;
    }
```

Now you can read your ID from FeedDetailFragment

```
if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            ID= getArguments().getLong(ARG_ITEM_ID, -1);
        }
```